# pg_stat_activity shows lots of easy queries running for minutes

Tags: postgresql, locking

After application server start its connection pool fills quickly and application can't work properly.
I went through pg_stat_activity and noticed lots of queries running for minutes:
[image]

But postgres's slow query log does not show any long-running queries (i've set 100ms as minimum query time).

```
select max(x2.x3) from (select "persistence_id" as x4, "sequence_number" as x3 from "persistence_journal" where "persistence_id" = $1 order by "sequence_number" desc) x2 where x2.x3 >= $2
```

I suggested that there are some locks on that table but `SELECT relation::regclass, * FROM pg_locks WHERE NOT GRANTED;` shows nothing.

Structure of persistence_journal is pretty easy:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.persistence_journal (
  persistence_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  sequence_number BIGINT NOT NULL,
  created BIGINT NOT NULL,
  tags VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  message BYTEA NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(persistence_id, sequence_number)
);
```

`persistence_journal` contains 1 678 121 rows with ~37 000 unique `persistence_id`s with average 44 rows per persistence_id.

Running `SELECT state, count(*) FROM pg_stat_activity GROUP BY state;`
 shows:

```
active  1
idle    43
idle in transaction 45
```

This "transaction" contains two pretty simple queries:

`select max(x2.x3) from (select "persistence_id" as x4, "sequence_number" as x3 from "persistence_journal" where "persistence_id" = $1 order by "sequence_number" desc) x2 where x2.x3 >= $2
select max("deleted_to") from "persistence_deleted_to" where "persistence_id" = $1`

`persistence_deleted_to` contains zero rows.

System's top shows almost zero CPU load.

PostgreSQL 9.4, Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem are the "idle in transaction" sessions.  You should fix your application to avoid that.  The queries in `pg_stat_activity` in those cases are the last query run, not the current one (since there isn't a current one).

Comment: I removed transaction (since I realized that I don't need any transaciton there) and the problem gone. But I am wondering how such simple read-only queries could lock each other?

Comment: FIgured out that it's db library bug: https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1492